# Change User-Agent in developer tools in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, user-agent

I am working on an web application that needs its settings as followed ( changed manually in Developer tools ):

Document-mode: IE=7
User-Agent: IE=7

With this settings it will be rendered correctly.

I was able to change the document-mode via HTTPRequest and/or FacesContext automatically, but is there a way to change the User-Agent automatically, too?
It could be with JSF, JavaScript, or whatever is possible.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: *"With this settings it will be rendered correctly"* http://xyproblem.info Real answer is: just use HTML5 doctype and write CSS following web standards, not MS proprietary rules.

Comment: That is clear. Our ( my ) problem is that a lot of other people has already worked on this application and if I change it in one place the somewhere else something will not work, and they want to have a fast solution.

Comment: Bite the bullet (or use a meta head to enforce document mode, see IE documentation).

Comment: Document mode is already set, so that is working. I am just working on the User - Agent settings in developer console, but it seems as if I have to go the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the X-UA-Compatible HTTP header to enforce document mode 7? If you do this, I think IE will change the JavaScript (client-side) user agent appropriately.

Comment: Yes, this is already implemented and it changed the Document mode, but what I need is the User-Agent set to the right IE, too.

Comment: Do you need the user-agent set correctly as it appears to the server, as it appears to JavaScript, or both?

Comment: I would need the Document mode set correctly, what I have already achieved, however, the site is only working in the correct way when the user-agent is set correctly, too. I tested it in the debugging mode and there I set it both ( Document mode and User-Agent ) to IE=7, then everything worked as expected.

Comment: So, I went a little bit further with my problem. I get this error
Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.ui.RootRenderingContext.getRendererManager(RootRenderingContext.java:196) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.uinode.UIXComponentUINode.getRenderer(UIXComponentUINode.java:379)
when using X-UA-Compatible", "IE=7" - If I turn the User-Agent in Emulation to IE=7, too, everything works as expected.